# Use of comma in a typedef declaration?

Tags: c, typedef, c11

Is this declaration C99/C11 compliant ?

```
typedef struct element {
    char *data; 
    struct element* next;
} element, *list, elements[5];
```

I could not find why it works in the standard.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it is standard compliant. `typedef` declarations are like normal declarations except the identifiers declared by them become type aliases for the type of object the identifier would be if the declaration had no `typedef` in it.

So while

```
int integer, *pointer_to_integer;
```

declares an `int` object named `integer` and an `int *` object named `pointer_to_integer`

```
typedef int integer, *pointer_to_integer;
```

would declare an `int`-typed type alias named `integer` and an `int *`-typed type alias named `pointer_to_integer`.

From a syntactical perspective, though not functionally, `typedef` is just a (fake) storage classifier (like `extern`, `auto`, `static`, `register` or `_Thread_local`).

Your declaration

```
typedef struct element {
    char *data; 
    struct element* next;
} element, *list, elements[5];
```

is slightly more complicated because it also *defines* the `struct element` data type but it's equivalent to:

```
struct element {
    char *data; 
    struct element* next;
}; 
// <= definition of the `struct element` data type
// also OK if it comes after the typedefs
// (the `struct element` part of the typedef would then
// sort of forward-declare the struct )

/*the type aliases: */
typedef struct element 
      element, *list, elements[5];
```

-- it declares `element` as a type alias to `struct element`, `list` as a type alias to `struct element *` and `elements` as a type alias to `struct element [5]`.

Comment: I always encourage to put all the typedefs before declarations.

Comment: @haccks I always encourage not editing other people's code to a point where it can no longer compile. :D

Comment: Sorry for that. I misunderstood it completely. Apologies.

Comment: @haccks No problem :).

Comment: Great answer even for C++ learners. Just keep in mind that the syntax is slightly different in C++ (the OP's question is tagged with C)

Answer (score 1):

In the C grammar, the `typedef` keyword acts like a storage-class specifier (like `extern`, `static`), per C 2018 6.7.1, and a type definition is simply a declaration. Like other declarations, it may have a list of *declarators* separated by commas (6.7 1).

The `typedef` in the question defines `element` to be an alias for the `struct element` type, `list` to be an alias for a type that is a pointer to a `struct element`, and `elements` to be an alias for a type that is an array of 5 `struct element`.