# typedef in c: struct or function reference?

Tags: c, struct, constants, typedef

Analyzing some part of software written by someone else, I found the following line of code:

```
typedef const struct rpc_method *(*super_t)(RPC*);
```

Ok, i know,

```
typedef rpc_method *(*super_t)(RPC*);
```

declares a type `super_t` which is a function pointer... 
I also know what `typedef struct` means, but the combination of the two?? 
Is it a struct with a single entry??? 
And what means `const` in this context?? 
Could it be that `const` and `struct` are exchanged???
Nevertheless seems to compile with my gcc eabi.

Comment: `const struct rpc_method *` is the return type of the function (i.e. a pointer to a constant rpc_method struct)

Answer (score 0):

If a declaration *without* `typedef` would declare a variable `IDENTIFIER` as an object of type `TYPE`, a declaration *with* `typedef` declares `IDENTIFIER` as type alias for type `TYPE` (i.e., the same type that the variable in the same declaration without the `typedef` would have).

So given that

```
struct rpc_method const*(*super_t)(RPC*);
```

declares `super_t` as a pointer to a function taking a pointer to `RCP` and returning a pointer to `struct rpc_method const`,

```
typedef struct rpc_method const*(*super_t)(RPC*);
```

declares `super_t` as a type alias for the type of the above pointer (to a function taking a pointer to `RCP` and returning a pointer to `struct rpc_method const`).

The `const` in the above declaration qualifies the target of the return type, whether you write it as `struct rpc_method const*` or `const struct rpc_method*` (putting the qualifer at the right hand side of the type works makes it more consistent with qualifiers put in other linkes of a chained pointer E.g., in `struct foo const * const * volatile bar` the last two `const` and `volatile` have to be at the right hand side of their `*`, while the first `const` could go left of `struct foo` with no change of semantics.

More details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57793519/1084774