# Cannot understand const struct in a declaration

Tags: c++, function, struct, constants, return-type

I found the following pieceof code:

```
  template<class C>
  const struct rpc_method *rpc_super(RPC *this_ptr) {
    return static_cast<C*>(this_ptr)->C::get_rpc_methods();
  }
```

Ok, seems a function template with output type `rpc_method *` 
which is indeed a struct, but why need `struct` here? 
Now, I try to understand the `const` modifier in conjunction with `struct`. 
Does `const` refer to the function or to the return value? 
Which role plays the `struct` keyword here??

Comment: this is not [tag:c].

Comment: Was just about to say the same. This looks c++ ish.

Comment: C requires the `struct`; in C++ it's optional. As for the rest , I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/61453964/1084774 answers it in your very related but more C-oriented (rather than C++-oriented) question.

Comment: Regarding the const, it refers to the pointed-to return object. I.e. a pointer to an object that is `const`. If it (pointlessly) applied to the pointer itself it would follow the `'*'`, preceding the function name. If it applied to the function itself (which must be a member function) it would follow the closing paren of the argument list, preceding the open-brace.